# HIbernate - "could not initialize proxy - no Session" error when trying to fetch data

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity-relationship

I am using spring boot and hibernate with MySql and I am trying to figure out the best way to handle the error

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: "some class field" could not initialize proxy - no Session".
```

I saw couple of solutions but I couldn't make them work, and also I do not understand the repercussions of implementing them.

I have the following Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="machine_groups_to_versions")
@Getter
@Setter
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(value= {"machineGroup", "version"})
public class MachineGroupToVersion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "machine_groups_to_versions_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "machine_groups_to_versions_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id", nullable = false)
    private MachineGroup machineGroup;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id", nullable = false)
    private Version version;
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "tested_time")
    private Date testedTime;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Date creationTime;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="versions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Version {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "versions_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "versions_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Date creationTime;
    @Column(name = "exe_file")
    @Lob
    private Blob exeFile;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "versions", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set<MachineGroup> machineGroups = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="machine_groups")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MachineGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "machine_groups_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "machine_groups_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 2)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private Date creationTime;
    @Column(name = "is_official")
    private boolean official;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "machine_properties_id", nullable = false)
    private ContinuousIntegrationProperties defaultContinuousIntegrationProperties;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_groups_to_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_groups_to_versions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "version_id"))
    private Set<Version> versions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

My Controller:

```
   @GetMapping("/getByMachineGroupName/{machineGroupName}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<MachineGroupToVersionDTO>> getAllVersions(@PathVariable String machineGroupName) {
        logger.info("Incoming GetMachineGroupToVersionReport Request. Machine Group Name: {}", machineGroupName);

        List<MachineGroupToVersionDTO> omgtv = machineGroupToVersionService.getByMachineGroupName(machineGroupName).stream()
     .map(this::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(omgtv, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I debug I can see that my omgtv has all the data I need but for some reason it is unable to return it.

As you can see in my MachineGroupToVersion class I extract MachineGroup and Version, the issue I see is:

1. MachineGroup is referencing a set of versions and each version references a set of MachineGroup
2. Same for the Version class

Looks like a cyclic issue with how the tables are created.
I have tried to use the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation but it just removes it from the response which is not the desired outcome.

I see the trace that shows what the error is but how can I fix this?

```
through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->entities.machinegrouptoversion.MachineGroupToVersionDTO[\"machineGroup\"]->entities.machinegroup.MachineGroup[\"users\"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->entities.user.User[\"machineGroups\"]
```

I don't want to make everything eager unless I specifically call the get function.

How can I resolve this without changing the structure of my classes and DB?

UPDATE:

Service

- List item

```
 @Transactional(transactionManager = "primaryTransactionManager", propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public List<MachineGroupToVersionDTO> getByMachineGroupName(String mgName) {
        List<MachineGroupToVersionDTO> mgtvl = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional<MachineGroup> mg = machineGroupService.getByName(mgName);
        if(mg.isPresent())
            mgtvl = machineGroupToVersionRepository.findByMachineGroup(mg.get()).stream()
                    .map(this::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return mgtvl;
    }

    private MachineGroupToVersionDTO convertToDto(MachineGroupToVersion mgtv) {
        MachineGroupToVersionDTO machineGroupToVersionDTO = new MachineGroupToVersionDTO();
        machineGroupToVersionDTO.setMachineGroup(mgtv.getMachineGroup());
        machineGroupToVersionDTO.setVersion(mgtv.getVersion());
        machineGroupToVersionDTO.setCreationTime(mgtv.getCreationTime());
        machineGroupToVersionDTO.setState(mgtv.getState());
        machineGroupToVersionDTO.setTestedTime(mgtv.getTestedTime());
        return machineGroupToVersionDTO;

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have `@Transactional` in `machineGroupToVersionService` and your conversion to DTO tries to load additional things. Either load everything eagerly or move your DTO conversion to service.

Comment: I don't have @Transcantional in the service. What do you mean by moving the DTO conversion to the service? What difference does it make where the convertToDto method will be created?

Comment: Also when I load everything eagerly the payload is very very very large and I am unable to process it in the client side...

Comment: Difference would be if you had `@Transactional` there. Point is you need the data, so you need to either fetch it eagerly, or do the DTO conversion while Hibernate session is still active, so it can still be loaded. Try adding `@Transactional` to the service and move dto conversion there, even if you don't want that - just to check if it works.

Comment: Please see the update in the question, it did not work. Unless I did something wrong

Comment: You are not fully mapping to DTO - `machineGroupToVersionDTO.setMachineGroup(mgtv.getMachineGroup());`. You need to map the whole structure, you are passing an entity here.

Comment: It does not work as well when I use modelMapper class to map between them, even though it does work on every other controller I have.

Comment: I am trying everything but it just doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @Shadov I was able to find the issue. In my case the issue was a mistake made by me when creating the DTO.

I mistakenly created the DTO with fields which are Entities and not other DTOs. Once I changed them from entities to DTOs I was able to get the response I needed.

Changed from this:

```
public class MachineGroupToVersionDTO {
    private MachineGroup machineGroup;
    private Version version;
    private String state;
    private Date testedTime;
    private Date creationTime;
}
```

To this:

```
public class MachineGroupToVersionDTO {
    private MachineGroupSimpleDTO machineGroup;
    private VersionDTO version;
    private String state;
    private Date testedTime;
    private Date creationTime;
}
```